# Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found

Tags: gulp, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am building an application customizer for our SharePoint online site, but i keep getting this error:-

```
Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'D:/extensionForFullstack/extension-for-fullstack/release/manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully
```

when i run `gulp package-solution --ship`. here is the full outputs from creating the solution till getting the error:-

```
D:\>md extensionForFullstack
D:\>cd D:\extensionForFullstack
D:\extensionForFullstack>yo @microsoft/sharepoint

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │      Welcome to the      │
    |--(o)--|    │  SharePoint Client-side  │
   `---------´   │         Solution         │
    ( _´U`_ )    │     Generator@1.13.0     │
    /___A___\   /╰──────────────────────────╯
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

Let's create a new SharePoint solution.
? What is your solution name? extension-for-fullstack
? Only SharePoint Online (latest) is supported.  For earlier versions of SharePoint (2016 and 2019) please use the 1.4.1 version of the generator. SharePoint Online only (latest)
? Where do you want to place the files? Create a subfolder with solution name
? Do you want to allow the tenant admin the choice of being able to deploy the solution to all sites immediately without running any feature deployment or adding apps in sites? Yes
? Will the components in the solution require permissions to access web APIs that are unique and not shared with other components in the tenant? Yes
? Which type of client-side component to create? Extension
? Which type of client-side extension to create? Application Customizer
Add new Application Customizer to solution extension-for-fullstack.
? What is your Application Customizer name? HelloWorld
? What is your Application Customizer description? HelloWorld description

    force .yo-rc.json
    force extension-for-fullstack\.yo-rc.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\config\package-solution.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\package.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\config\config.json
   create config\serve.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\tsconfig.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\.vscode\extensions.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\.vscode\launch.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\.vscode\settings.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\config\deploy-azure-storage.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\config\serve.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\config\write-manifests.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\src\index.ts
   create extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
   create extension-for-fullstack\README.md
   create extension-for-fullstack\tslint.json
   create extension-for-fullstack\.gitignore
   create extension-for-fullstack\.npmignore
   create src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.ts
   create src\extensions\helloWorld\loc\en-us.js
   create src\extensions\helloWorld\loc\myStrings.d.ts
   create src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
   create sharepoint\assets\ClientSideInstance.xml
   create sharepoint\assets\elements.xml

No change to package.json was detected. No package manager install will be executed.


      _=+#####!
   ###########|       .------------------------------------------------.
   ###/    (##|(@)    |                Congratulations!                |
   ###  ######|   \   |  Solution extension-for-fullstack is created.  |
   ###/   /###|   (@) |         Run gulp serve to play with it!        |
   #######  ##|   /   '------------------------------------------------'
   ###     /##|(@)
   ###########|
      **=+####!


D:\extensionForFullstack>code .

D:\extensionForFullstack>cd D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>Gulp build
[11:47:56] Local modules not found in D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack
[11:47:56] Try running: npm install

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack> npm install
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated @types/anymatch@3.0.0: This is a stub types definition. anymatch provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated @opentelemetry/types@0.2.0: Package renamed to @opentelemetry/api, see https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.1.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

> node-sass@4.14.1 install D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\**\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.14.1\win32-x64-83_binding.node

> es5-ext@0.10.61 postinstall D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\node_modules\es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0


> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.nodeTesting binary
Binary is fine
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.2 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\@rushstack\typings-generator\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN office-ui-fabric-react@7.176.2 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 <17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN office-ui-fabric-react@7.176.2 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@>=16.8.0 <17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fluentui/theme@1.7.6 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fluentui/theme@1.7.6 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @uifabric/utilities@7.34.1 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @uifabric/utilities@7.34.1 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fluentui/react-focus@7.18.4 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fluentui/react-focus@7.18.4 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fluentui/react-window-provider@1.0.3 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fluentui/react-window-provider@1.0.3 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @uifabric/react-hooks@7.14.2 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @uifabric/react-hooks@7.14.2 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @uifabric/foundation@7.10.3 requires a peer of @types/react@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @uifabric/foundation@7.10.3 requires a peer of @types/react-dom@>=16.8.0 <18.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 2240 packages from 1001 contributors and audited 2246 packages in 343.341s

123 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 120 vulnerabilities (20 low, 55 moderate, 42 high, 3 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>Gulp build
Build target: DEBUG
[11:54:45] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[11:54:45] Starting 'build'...
[11:54:45] Starting gulp
[11:54:45] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[11:54:45] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 127 ms
[11:54:45] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[11:54:45] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[11:54:45] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 21 ms
[11:54:45] Finished subtask 'sass' after 12 ms
[11:54:45] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[11:54:46] [tslint] tslint version: 5.20.1
[11:54:46] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[11:54:46] [tsc] typescript version: 3.9.10
[11:54:46] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 867 ms
[11:54:47] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 1.37 s
[11:54:47] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[11:54:47] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 211 μs
[11:54:47] Finished 'build' after 1.52 s
[11:54:47] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[11:54:48] Project extension-for-fullstack version:0.0.1
[11:54:48] Build tools version:3.17.17
[11:54:48] Node version:v14.18.1
[11:54:48] Total duration:20 s

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>Gulp bundle -ship

Usage: gulp [options] tasks

Options:
  --help, -h              Show this help.                              [boolean]
  --version, -v           Print the global and local gulp versions.    [boolean]
  --require               Will require a module before running the gulpfile.
                          This is useful for transpilers but also has other
                          applications.                                 [string]
  --gulpfile, -f          Manually set path of gulpfile. Useful if you have
                          multiple gulpfiles. This will set the CWD to the
                          gulpfile directory as well.                   [string]
  --cwd                   Manually set the CWD. The search for the gulpfile, as
                          well as the relativity of all requires will be from
                          here.                                         [string]
  --verify                Will verify plugins referenced in project's
                          package.json against the plugins blacklist.
  --tasks, -T             Print the task dependency tree for the loaded
                          gulpfile.                                    [boolean]
  --tasks-simple          Print a plaintext list of tasks for the loaded
                          gulpfile.                                    [boolean]
  --tasks-json            Print the task dependency tree, in JSON format, for
                          the loaded gulpfile.
  --tasks-depth, --depth  Specify the depth of the task dependency tree.[number]
  --compact-tasks         Reduce the output of task dependency tree by printing
                          only top tasks and their child tasks.        [boolean]
  --sort-tasks            Will sort top tasks of task dependency tree. [boolean]
  --color                 Will force gulp and gulp plugins to display colors,
                          even when no color support is detected.      [boolean]
  --no-color              Will force gulp and gulp plugins to not display
                          colors, even when color support is detected. [boolean]
  --silent, -S            Suppress all gulp logging.                   [boolean]
  --continue              Continue execution of tasks upon failure.    [boolean]
  --series                Run tasks given on the CLI in series (the default is
                          parallel).                                   [boolean]
  --log-level, -L         Set the loglevel. -L for least verbose and -LLLL for
                          most verbose. -LLL is default.                 [count]


D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>Gulp bundle --ship
Build target: SHIP
[11:54:58] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[11:54:58] Starting 'bundle'...
[11:54:58] Starting gulp
[11:54:58] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[11:54:58] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 66 ms
[11:54:58] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[11:54:58] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[11:54:58] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 28 ms
[11:54:58] Finished subtask 'sass' after 16 ms
[11:54:58] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[11:54:58] [tslint] tslint version: 5.20.1
[11:54:58] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[11:54:58] [tsc] typescript version: 3.9.10
[11:54:58] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 780 ms
[11:54:59] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 951 ms
[11:54:59] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[11:54:59] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 1.53 ms
[11:54:59] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[11:54:59] Error - 'configure-webpack' sub task errored after 199 ms
 File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json'
[11:54:59] 'bundle' errored after 1.26 s
[11:54:59]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>Gulp package-solution --ship
Build target: SHIP
[11:55:09] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[11:55:09] Starting 'package-solution'...
[11:55:09] Starting gulp
[11:55:09] Starting subtask 'package-solution'...
[11:55:10] Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\release/manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully
[11:55:10] Finished subtask 'package-solution' after 33 ms
[11:55:10] Finished 'package-solution' after 38 ms
[11:55:10] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'D:/extensionForFullstack/extension-for-fullstack/release/manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully
[11:55:11] Project extension-for-fullstack version:0.0.1
[11:55:11] Build tools version:3.17.17
[11:55:11] Node version:v14.18.1
[11:55:11] Total duration:3.31 s
[11:55:11] Task errors:1
The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr.
Exiting with exit code: 1

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>gulp bundle
Build target: DEBUG
[11:57:10] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[11:57:10] Starting 'bundle'...
[11:57:10] Starting gulp
[11:57:10] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[11:57:10] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 47 ms
[11:57:10] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[11:57:10] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[11:57:10] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 20 ms
[11:57:10] Finished subtask 'sass' after 11 ms
[11:57:10] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[11:57:10] [tslint] tslint version: 5.20.1
[11:57:10] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[11:57:10] [tsc] typescript version: 3.9.10
[11:57:11] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 727 ms
[11:57:11] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 856 ms
[11:57:11] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[11:57:11] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 206 μs
[11:57:11] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[11:57:11] Error - 'configure-webpack' sub task errored after 185 ms
 File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json'
[11:57:11] 'bundle' errored after 1.12 s
[11:57:11]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1


D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>gulp package-solution --ship
Build target: SHIP
[11:57:32] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[11:57:32] Starting 'package-solution'...
[11:57:32] Starting gulp
[11:57:32] Starting subtask 'package-solution'...
[11:57:32] Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\release/manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully
[11:57:32] Finished subtask 'package-solution' after 19 ms
[11:57:32] Finished 'package-solution' after 24 ms
[11:57:33] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'D:/extensionForFullstack/extension-for-fullstack/release/manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully
[11:57:33] Project extension-for-fullstack version:0.0.1
[11:57:33] Build tools version:3.17.17
[11:57:33] Node version:v14.18.1
[11:57:33] Total duration:3.3 s
[11:57:33] Task errors:1
The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr.
Exiting with exit code: 1

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>gulp bundle --ship
Build target: SHIP
[12:00:07] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[12:00:07] Starting 'bundle'...
[12:00:07] Starting gulp
[12:00:07] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[12:00:07] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 58 ms
[12:00:07] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[12:00:07] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[12:00:07] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 28 ms
[12:00:07] Finished subtask 'sass' after 16 ms
[12:00:07] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[12:00:07] [tslint] tslint version: 5.20.1
[12:00:07] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[12:00:07] [tsc] typescript version: 3.9.10
[12:00:08] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 745 ms
[12:00:08] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 892 ms
[12:00:08] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[12:00:08] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 1.35 ms
[12:00:08] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[12:00:08] Error - 'configure-webpack' sub task errored after 165 ms
 File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json'
[12:00:08] 'bundle' errored after 1.16 s
[12:00:08]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>gulp clean
Build target: DEBUG
[12:00:24] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[12:00:24] Starting 'clean'...
[12:00:24] Starting gulp
[12:00:24] Starting subtask 'clean'...
[12:00:24] Finished subtask 'clean' after 7.45 ms
[12:00:24] Finished 'clean' after 12 ms
[12:00:24] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[12:00:25] Project extension-for-fullstack version:0.0.1
[12:00:25] Build tools version:3.17.17
[12:00:25] Node version:v14.18.1
[12:00:25] Total duration:3.47 s

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>gulp bundle --ship
Build target: SHIP
[12:00:36] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[12:00:36] Starting 'bundle'...
[12:00:36] Starting gulp
[12:00:36] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[12:00:36] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 55 ms
[12:00:36] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[12:00:36] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[12:00:36] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 32 ms
[12:00:36] Finished subtask 'sass' after 19 ms
[12:00:36] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[12:00:36] [tslint] tslint version: 5.20.1
[12:00:36] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[12:00:36] [tsc] typescript version: 3.9.10
[12:00:36] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 760 ms
[12:00:37] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 908 ms
[12:00:37] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[12:00:37] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 1.38 ms
[12:00:37] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[12:00:37] Error - 'configure-webpack' sub task errored after 166 ms
 File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json'
[12:00:37] 'bundle' errored after 1.18 s
[12:00:37]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>gulp bundle --ship
Build target: SHIP
[12:03:06] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[12:03:06] Starting 'bundle'...
[12:03:06] Starting gulp
[12:03:06] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[12:03:06] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 45 ms
[12:03:06] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[12:03:06] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[12:03:06] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 20 ms
[12:03:06] Finished subtask 'sass' after 11 ms
[12:03:06] Starting subtask 'tslint'...
[12:03:06] [tslint] tslint version: 5.20.1
[12:03:06] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[12:03:06] [tsc] typescript version: 3.9.10
[12:03:07] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 733 ms
[12:03:07] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 886 ms
[12:03:07] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[12:03:07] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 1.35 ms
[12:03:07] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[12:03:07] Error - 'configure-webpack' sub task errored after 163 ms
 File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
File does not exist: D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\src\extensions\helloWorld\HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.manifest.json'
[12:03:07] 'bundle' errored after 1.13 s
[12:03:07]
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>gulp package-solution --ship
Build target: SHIP
[12:03:13] Using gulpfile D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\gulpfile.js
[12:03:13] Starting 'package-solution'...
[12:03:13] Starting gulp
[12:03:13] Starting subtask 'package-solution'...
[12:03:13] Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack\release/manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully
[12:03:13] Finished subtask 'package-solution' after 14 ms
[12:03:13] Finished 'package-solution' after 18 ms
[12:03:14] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - [package-solution] No manifests were found in 'D:/extensionForFullstack/extension-for-fullstack/release/manifests'. Ensure a build has completed successfully
[12:03:14] Project extension-for-fullstack version:0.0.1
[12:03:14] Build tools version:3.17.17
[12:03:14] Node version:v14.18.1
[12:03:14] Total duration:3.23 s
[12:03:14] Task errors:1
The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr.
Exiting with exit code: 1

D:\extensionForFullstack\extension-for-fullstack>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with app customzier project generated if you select "create a solution subfolder" in the version 1.13 of the wizard (a bug). Some required folders are created in the root folder, even if you select "use subfolder" option. These folders include the manifest folder.

To fix the things you could:

- use the latest version (1.14) of SPFx tools. Version 1.14 does not provide the subfolder option anymore, so you won't be able to select it, and there should be no problem :)
- Alternatively, select "use current folder" (default) when creating a project using 1.13 wizard, not "create subfolder". Should also work.